# Existence of Kan extension in KS Categories and Sheaves

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

I was trying to read Kashiwara-Schapira proof of existence of Kan extension. When target category is complete, and the other categories are small.

My interpretation of Kan extensions and the idea for approaching the existence is as follows;

Kan extensions are approximate extension of a functor, approximation in the categorical sense will be in terms of morphisms, since we are in the functor category, it will be natural transformations. What we want is a limit in the category of all “right extensions”. i.e., any other extension has to factor through this “limit” extension. This is just saying it’s the best approximation from the left.

The theorem due to Kan states that, if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are small, and $\mathcal{C}$ is complete the right Kan extension exists.

This makes sense because functor category to $\mathcal{C}$ will also be complete and limits will exist and if $\mathcal{B}$ is locally small, then the functor category $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{B}$ will be locally small.

We just have to make sure it’s an inductive system now. So, we have to make sure the collection of all right extensions is at most a set, and get a functor from that set to the extensions.

I expect this is what’s happening in the proof, but can’t parse through the proof. I did not like the proofs in other books because they invloved new definitions like end, coend or comma categories.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Randall In the statement, they describe a limit $\lim_{(\phi(j)\to i)\in J_i} \beta(j)$, what's this? They don't seem to define it.

Comment: I can accept [although I am of a different opinion ] that you might find the machinery of coends too abstract to grasp basic Kan extensions, but comma categories are exactly what you need! This said, KS should define $J_i$ right before 2.3.3.

Comment: I checked and... apparently, they just don't define it, or they hide it very well! Anyway, the category that they call $J_i$ is precisely the comma category $(\varphi/i)$ (nd you *need* it to define a left/right Kan extension as a colimit/limit), so as you can see there is no escape from abstraction!

Comment: Any accessible intro to ends/coends you can recommend? Preferrably doesn't have too many prereqs

Comment: I've heard this book is decent https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503, and there's an appendix on basic Category Theory, starting from the very beginning.

Comment: @fosco :)) first chapter should be sufficient? I only wanted to understand what abelian categories are, and the rabithole keeps going deeper and deeper

Comment: There isn't much Abelian category theory in my book, unfortunately! But maybe I can help with Kan extension (even though I find the notation and style of presentation in KS unbearably obscure...). Trust me, the only abstract concept you need is the definition of comma category!

Comment: (Special cases of) Comma categories and notation for them are defined in Definition 1.2.16. These are what is used to describe the diagram that the limit $\lim_{(\phi(j)\to i)\in J_i} \beta(j)$ is over.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Thank you! I will check it out

Comment: @fosco It seems to me that the coend formula for Kan extension manages to hide going to comma categories or category of elements, via natural transformations-end isomorphism. Although pretty cool, all the element nonsense is done in this isomorphism, and then proofs become chain of isomorphisms. Nice! I like this more theory, less hard proofs style.


Do you have any similar cool way of doing derived functors? I have currently done it via Kan extensions, following Georges Maltsiniotis. Any cooler approach without too much $\infty$-categories?

Comment: Kashiwara-Schapira seems hard probably because they do use lots of abstract stuff, but that still doesn’t reduce the difficulty of theorems.

Many of the stuff that are hard in KS, can probably be reduced to simpler proofs with like 10% extra theory/category theory.

Maybe there should be a balance between abstraction-hard proof. The preference of which varies for each person probably.

KS, hits the perfect place where it’s unbalanced for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Kan extension as already asserts that it arises as a certain limit or colimit (by virtue of being the value of a left or right adjoint) of functors. The exsitence theorem however, does not amount to verifying directly that those limits or colimtis exist. Instead, the existence theorem asserts that the values of the extension may arise as limits or colimits of objects, and that if those limits or colimits exist, then they assemble into the extension.

Consider functors $\phi\colon J\to I$ and $\beta\colon J\to C$, and a right extension $\psi\colon I\to C$ whose counit natural trasformation $\psi\circ\phi\Rightarrow\beta$ with components $\psi\circ\phi(j)\to\beta(j)$. This extension determines for each morphism $i\to\phi(j)$ in $I$, a morphism $\psi(i)\to\psi\circ\phi(j)\to\beta(j)$.

The key idea is that these morphisms $\psi(i)\to\phi(j)$ associated to each $i\to\phi(j)$ can be interpreted as a family indexed by the category $I$ of cones with vertices $\psi(i)$ over diagrams in $C$ indexed by categories $J^i$, that is natural in the variable $i$.

Explicitly, following the notation of KS (Definition 1.2.16), for each object $i$ of $I$, an object of the category $J^i$ (a special kind of comma category) is a pairs of an object $j$ of $J$ and a morphisms $i\to\phi(j)$ in $I$. A morphism in $J^i$ from such an object $i\to\phi(j)$ to another object $i\to\phi(j')$  is a morphism $j\to j'$ in $J$ for which $i\to\phi(j')$ factors as $i\to\phi(j)\to\phi(j')$.

The diagram in $C$ indexed by $J^i$ takes a morphism between $i\to\phi(j)$ and $i\to\phi(j')$ given by $j\to j'$ in $J$ to the morphism $\beta(j)\to\beta(j')$. That sending an object $i\to\phi(j)$ to $\psi(i)\to\psi\circ\phi(j)\to\beta(j)$ is a cone over the diagram follows from naturality of the transformation $\psi\circ\phi\Rightarrow\beta$.

Naturality of the family of cones amounts to the fact that, given a morphism $i'\to i$ in $I$, pre-composition with $\psi(i')\to\psi(i)$ sends the cone with vertex $\psi(i)$ over the diagram indexed by $J^i$ to the cone with vertex $\psi(i')$ over the diagram indexed by $J^{i'}$.

Finally, given merely such a family of cones sending morphisms $i\to\phi(j)$ in $I$ to morphisms $\psi(i)\to\beta(j)$, evidently the morphisms $\psi(i')\to\psi(i)$ form a functor, and the morphisms $\psi(\phi(j))\to\beta(j)$ given by taking $i=\phi(j)$, form a natural transformation $\psi\circ\phi\Rightarrow\beta$.

Thus there is a bijective correspondence between right extensions and such natural families of cones over the diagrams indexed by $J^i$. Moreover, one can check that a factorization of one extension through another corresponds to a factorization of one natural family of cones through another natural family of cones. The existence of a right Kan extension amounts to having a terminal object in this category of natural families of cones. The existence theorem for right Kan extension asserts that such a terminal object exists if (but not only if!) each diagram in the family has a limit. Indeed, then their limiting cones assemble into a natural family of cones (using the universal property of limits), hence determine a right extension. Moreover, every other natural family of cones factors uniquely through that natural family of cones (again using the universal property of limits).